# "Menubar-Widget" doesn't update its interface

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mac-app-store

I'm trying to create a small "Menubar-Widget". So it's not really a widget, but it's a Cocoa-Application, which has no icon in the dock but an icon in the menu- or statusbar.

You can fire a NSTimer by clicking a button, and then it should show a countdown. But it doesn't...

```
- (void)update {
    NSTimeInterval interval = [endDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    int _seconds = (int)interval%60;
    int _minutes = (((int)interval-_seconds)/60)%60;
    int _hours = ((int)interval-_seconds-_minutes*60)%3600;

    timeLeft.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i:%i",_hours,_minutes,_seconds];

    NSLog(@"%i:%i:%i",_hours,_minutes,_seconds);
}
```

So what happen exactly?

When I fire the timer, the interface won't update the timeLeft Label. NSLog() won't work too. But if I close the box, the NSLog says me the correct time and if I open the box again, it's showing me the right thing. But it won't update anymore 'til I close the box again.

[image: "Menubar-Widget"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the relative time with an absolute time (e.g. 2:45 pm)... Interface is still not updating, but it's ok.